# Gerar uma data após uma data específica

Tags: r

Tenho uma coluna de uma tabela com datas, preciso criar uma outra coluna com datas aleatórias e posteriores a esta. Usei a função seq.Date para isso mas recebo o seguinte erro.

```
date_arq<-seq.Date(as.Date(base$DATE_END, "%Y-%m-%d"))
Error in seq.Date(as.Date(base$DATE_END, "%Y-%m-%d")) : 
  'from' deve ter comprimento 1
```

As datas da coluna DATE_END tem uma cara 2013-09-16, por exemplo. Não existe nenhuma célula com data em branco, todas estão no mesmo formato.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há várias coisas erradas com o seu código.

Em primeiro lugar, as seguintes duas instruções são equivalentes, uma vez que o argumento `format` é `"%Y-%m-%d"` por defeito:

```
as.Date(base$DATE_END, "%Y-%m-%d")
as.Date(base$DATE_END)
```

Em segundo lugar, é melhor transformar toda a coluna `DATE_END` em classe `Date` uma única vez, logo no início do código, e depois usá-la já como uma data. Esta base é só um exemplo.

```
base <- data.frame(DATE_END = c("2013-02-25", "2013-05-14", "2013-09-16"))
base$DATE_END <- as.Date(base$DATE_END)
```

Em terceiro lugar, se o objeto é de classe `Date` o método `seq.Date` é automaticamente chamado quando se chama `seq(uma_data, etc)`. Não é necessário, *mas também não é errado*, chamar `seq.Date` explicitamente.

Além disso, faltam argumentos em `seq.Date`. O R precisa de saber o início da sequência e informação quanto à sequência, tal como:

- O fim e o incremento, argumentos `to` e `by`;
- O comprimento total, argumento `length.out`;
- O comprimento total igual ao comprimento de outra variável, argumento `along.with`.

Finalmente o código. Como diz que precisa de criar uma outra coluna com datas aleatórias e posteriores à coluna de datas que tem, começo por saber qual é a última data e depois crio uma sequência de datas daí até hoje. E é escolher aleatoriamente com `sample`. Neste caso estou a amostrar sem reposição. Veja `help("sample")`.

```
ult <- max(base$DATE_END)

set.seed(9447)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis
sqDt <- seq(ult + 1, Sys.Date(), by = "day")
base$DATE_ALEA <- sample(sqDt, nrow(base))

base
#    DATE_END  DATE_ALEA
#1 2013-02-25 2015-11-27
#2 2013-05-14 2017-10-24
#3 2013-09-16 2014-11-01
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Opa, tudo bem?

Também da pra fazer sem utilizar a função `seq()`:

```
# Criando um data frame de exemplo
base <- data.frame(
  DATE_END = as.Date(c("2017-02-15", "2017-04-08", "2017-09-13", "2017-11-20"))
)

# Identificando a maior data na coluna DATA_END
start <- max(base$DATE_END)

# Definindo faixa de datas aleatórias (data final - data inicial)
# Como exemplo adotei o Sys.Date() como data final
range <- Sys.Date() - start+1

# Garantindo a reprodução dos resultados aleatórios
set.seed(101)

# Criando a coluna DATA_SEQ e atribuindo as datas aleatórias
# Note que o a função nrow(base) vai garantir que a amostragem não ultrapasse 
# a quantidade de linhas do data frame
base$DATE_SEQ <- sample(start+1:range,nrow(base))

# Se quiser deixar as datas aleatórias em ordem crescente
base$DATE_SEQ <- sort(sample(start+1:range,nrow(base)))

print(base)

# DATE_END   DATE_SEQ
# 1 2017-02-15 2017-11-29
# 2 2017-04-08 2018-02-03
# 3 2017-09-13 2018-03-29
# 4 2017-11-20 2018-04-09
```